# Java applets alternatives for smart card read in browser

Tags: java, browser, applet, smartcard

I'm trying to find answer what is the java applet alternative for reading certificate from smart card in browser?

At the moment, I'm using Java applet but as Google is not supporting NPAPI plugin in Chrome I need to find alternative which is much or less browser-agnostic and works at least in most popular browsers. I'm not sure if I'm correct but I think Oracle and IBM has their own solutions used on their application servers but I would need free one that I can use independently.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in a right direction ;)